# How do I synchronize a Outlook Calendar in Share Point using a Calendar Web App?

Tags: sharepoint, outlook, calendar, sharepoint-2013

I have a calendar on a share point page and the customer would like it if we could synchronize a email address to display on the calendar.

The calendar is setup using a web app and I'm in Share Point 2013.

I have no clue how to do this and was messing around in the Calendar Overlay Settings but can't get it to work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can sync the Outlook calendar in SharePoint page using Outlook Rest API.

Follow [Get Outlook Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#get-events) to get all the events from outlook calendar.

[Register you Application](https://dev.outlook.com/AppRegistration)

See my workaround to bind Outlook calendar events in Jquery Full Calendar  in Sharepoint page.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/sites/xxx/SiteAssets/fullcalendar.css">          
<script src='/sites/xxx/SiteAssets/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src="/sites/xxx/SiteAssets/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<script src='/sites/xxx/SiteAssets/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='/sites/xxx/SiteAssets/fullcalendar.js'></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
    var even = new Array();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.support.cors = true;
        $.getScript('/sites/xxx/SiteAssets/fullcalendar.js', function () {
            $.getScript('/sites/xxx/SiteAssets/moment.min.js', GetAuthorizeCode);
        }
             );            

    });

    function GetAuthorizeCode() {
        var initialUri = window.location.href;
        if (initialUri.indexOf('code') == -1) {
            var url = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=[client_id of your application]&redirect_uri=https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/xxx/Site%20Pages/Test.aspx&resource=https:%2f%2foutlook.office365.com%2f&state=5fdfd60b-8457-4536-b20f-fcb658d19458";
            window.location.href = url;
        }
        else {
            var codeVal = getQueryStringParameter("code");
            var accessToken = getAccessToken(codeVal);               

        }
    }



    function getQueryStringParameter(param) {
        var params = document.URL.split("?")[1].split("&");
        var strParams = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i = i + 1) {
            var singleParam = params[i].split("=");
            if (singleParam[0] == param) {
                return singleParam[1];

            }
        }
    }

    function getAccessToken(code) {            
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "Url to get AccessToken",                
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                var accesstoken= data["AccessToken"];
                var events = GetEvents(accesstoken);

            },
            error: function (httpReq, status, exception) {
                debugger;
                return "";
            }
        });
    }

    function GetEvents(token) {
        debugger;
        var call = $.ajax({
            url: "https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            headers: {
                Accept: "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true",
                'Authorization': "Bearer " + token
            },
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;

                for (var i = 0; i < data.value.length ; i++) {
                    even.push({
                        title: data.value[i].Subject,
                        start: data.value[i].Start.DateTime,
                        url: data.value[i].WebLink,
                        end:data.value[i].End.DateTime
                    });
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    height: 450,
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                    },
                    disableDragging: true,                       
                    editable: false,
                    events: even,
                    eventClick: function (event) {
                        if (event.url) {
                            window.open(event.url);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
                 callback(events);
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                debugger;
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                    height: 450,
                    header: {
                        left: 'prev,next today',
                        center: 'title',
                        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
                    },
                    disableDragging: true,
                    editable: false,
                    events: []
                });
                return "";
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

Also you can add outlook calendar events in sharepoint list using Outlook Addins. Visual Studio 2015 supports to create a Webaddin which supports both Outlook Webapp and Outlook client.